# Could not find KDE installation - RKWard

Tags: r, linux-mint, kde-plasma

I installed Linux Mint Tricia in my pc and I also installed the R-base and RKWard using the Application Manager tool. The installation seems to work well, no error messages. However, when I try to open the RKWard the following message appears:

"The KDE installation could not be found (kreadconfig5). When moving / copying RKWard, make sure to copy the whole application folder, or create a shorcut / link, instead."

I never moved or copied the RKWard to other folder, so I suppose that this message is related to an installation error.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to install libkf5config-bin?

```
sudo apt-get install libkf5config-bin
```